# Solr atomic update does not work for me

Tags: solr, solr4, solr-query-syntax

I am going to do atomic update on solr with http request. I want to update the document with `id:"http://www.entekhab.ir"` setting `view="true"` I did call both of these http requests, but none of them works for me. Could you please tell me what part I did wrong?

```
http://10.102.1.30:8983/solr/collection1/update?commit=true -H 'Content-Type:text/xml'
'<add>
<doc>
<field
name="id">http://www.entekhab.ir/</field>
<field update="set"
name=
"view">
true
</field>
</doc>
</add>'

http://10.102.1.30:8983/solr/collection1/update?commit=true -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"http://www.entekhab.ir/","view":{"set":true}}]'
```

p.s: id field is uniquekey in my schema.xml

Comment: Do you get any response or error from the Solr server?

Comment: Yeah I got response like:
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">2</int>
</lst>
</response>

Comment: Old thread but just to give an idea. Have you tried from the Admin UI in the documents option? I think it is less error prone for testing.